# Expressing generalized cohomology by ordinary cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'd like to ask for either pointing an error or confirming correctness of the following reasoning.

Theorem: let $h^* \colon CW \to Ab$ be a cohomology theory, then there exist abelian groups $ \ldots,  G_{-1}, G_0, G_1, \ldots$ such that
$$
h^k(X) = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} H^i (Y, G_{i-k})
$$
Where $H^*$ denotes ordinary cohomology.

Idea of proof: by Brown representability theorem there exist spaces $X_i$ such that $X_i \sim \Omega X_{i+1}$, $X_i$ have homotopy type of CW-complexes and $h^i(Y) = [Y, X_i]$. We can make $X_i$ into H-spaces with strict identity (at least that's what Wikipedia article on H-spaces implicitly claims). Now there's a theorem (4K.7 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology)

> A path-connected, commutative, associative H-space with a strict
>   identity element has the weak homotopy type of a product of
>   Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

Applying the above to spaces $X_i$ we obtain, that there exist abelian groups $ \ldots G_{-1}, G_0, G_1, \ldots$ such that $X_j \sim \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} K(G_{i-j},i)$

Finally $$ h^k(Y) = [Y, X_k] = [Y, \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} K(G_{i-k})] = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} [Y, K(G_{i-k}, i)] = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} H^i(Y; G_{i-k}) $$ $\blacksquare$

Questions:

1. What (if anything) goes wrong?
2. If this happens to be true, what's the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the theorem is about *strict* commutativity and associativity. The spaces that represent cohomology theories in a fixed degree (namely infinite loop spaces) are almost never strictly commutative and associative (precisely because they are almost never products of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces); for example, the infinite loop space $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$ representing complex K-theory (in degree $0$) does not have this property.

Second, even when the theorem applies, the resulting equivalence is *not* guaranteed to be an equivalence of H-spaces, so you don't get to compare group structures. For a very explicit example see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196152/homologically-distinct-infinite-loop-structures-on-a-space/196156#196156).